# MVC Project within an MVC Project

Tags: c#, windows, model-view-controller, iis

On IIS, I can create a site for my MVC project, call it Foo.

Once I have it setup I can right-click on it and "add virtual directory" Bar.

If I try to make Bar a virtual directory, I get an error saying that probably this needs to be an application.

So I right-click and make Bar an application.  Still no go.

The issue is there's a clash with the web.config of Foo and Bar, saying one of my connection strings is already defined.

It seems that I can't just do `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` since that is not valid to use on the Config settings.

The only other idea I have is to create a web.release.config file in Bar, and delete every single thing that clashes with Foo.  This seems tedious and prone to error.

Any suggestions on how to have my url look the way I want it (www.foo.com/Bar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add a `<clear />` tag before any `<add ... />` tags in the child web.config. This removes all inherited added fields including every added field before the clear tag.

This should work for ConnectionStrings, AppSettings, etc. Basicly everything that relies on the `<add ... />` tag.

```
<!--FOO web.config-->
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DataBase1" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
   <add name="DataBase2" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
</connectionStrings>

<!--BAR web.config-->
<connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <add name="DataBase1" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
   <add name="DataBase2" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bar is just a directory?

You need to be using namespaces. Once you've defined your namespaces, they wont make the compiler clash on objects. Then in IIS you don't have to do anything except make foo your app.

```
namespace BarSpace {

    [classes/code]
}

namespace FooSpace {

 [classes/code]
}
```